# find if an integer exists in a list of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, integer

i have this code:

```
  List<T> apps = getApps();

        List<int> ids;

        List<SelectListItem> dropdown = apps.ConvertAll(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = ids.Contains(c.Id),
            Text = c.Name,
            Value = c.Id.ToString()
        }).ToList();


ids.Contains
```

seems to always return false even though the numbers do match

any ideas?

Comment: No, that's pretty much how you do it.

Comment: mquander is right - perhaps you can try a small example like List<int> foo = new List<int>();  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { foo.Add(i); } Console.WriteLine(foo.Contains(2));

Comment: I guess that you have a bug elsewhere.  That approach SHOULD work.

Comment: Like mquander said that's how you do it. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: the List<int> ids is not initialized to anything. try adding with some known values ~ var ids = new List<int>() {2,4,6,8};

Comment: see my answer below that has been updated 2x in response to your edits.

Comment: you must use  ids.Contains(IntParam) @leora

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you just need a true/false result

```
bool isInList = intList.IndexOf(intVariable) != -1;
```

if the intVariable does not exist in the List it will return -1

Comment: `IndexOf` is zero-based. That should be `>= 0` :)

Comment: Or really it should just check `!= -1` since the -1 return value is defined as the negative result.

Answer (score 88):

As long as your list is initialized with values and that value actually exists in the list, then Contains should return true.

I tried the following:

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
var intVar = 4;
var exists = list.Contains(intVar);
```

And exists is indeed set to true.

Comment: OP updated his question which you answer.  his ids list does not appear to be initialized.  Shouldn't that be a compiler catch?

Comment: Yeah. An uninitialized list should cause a compiler error. But not if the list is defined at class level, then it will be initialized to null and the compiler will be happy.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a extension method, this allows coding like the SQL IN command.

```
public static bool In<T>(this T o, params T[] values)
{
    if (values == null) return false;

    return values.Contains(o);
}
public static bool In<T>(this T o, IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    if (values == null) return false;

    return values.Contains(o);
}
```

This allows stuff like that:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>( new[] {1,5,7});
int i = 5;
bool isIn = i.In(ints);
```

Or:

```
int i = 5;
bool isIn = i.In(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Answer (score 6):

The way you did is correct. It works fine with that code: x is true.
probably you made a mistake somewhere else.

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>( new[] {1,5,7}); // 1
```

---

```
List<int> intlist=new List<int>() { 0,2,3,4,1}; // 2
```

---

```
var i = 5;
var x = ints.Contains(i);   // return true or false
```

Answer (score 3):

The best of code and complete is here:

```
NumbersList.Exists(p => p.Equals(Input)
```

Use:

```
List<int> NumbersList = new List<int>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Input = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    if (!NumbersList.Exists(p => p.Equals(Input)))
    {
       NumbersList.Add(Input);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The number entered is in the list","Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool vExist = false;
int vSelectValue = 1;

List<int> vList = new List<int>();
vList.Add(1);
vList.Add(2);

IEnumerable vRes = (from n in vListwhere n == vSelectValue);
if (vRes.Count > 0) {
    vExist = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be referencing `Selected` not `ids.Contains` as the last line.

I just realized this is a formatting issue, from the OP.  Regardless you should be referencing the value in Selected.  I recommend adding some Console.WriteLine calls to see exactly what is being printed out on each line and also what each value is.

After your update:
ids is an empty list, how is this not throwing a NullReferenceException?  As it was never initialized in that code block

Answer (score 0):

```
string name= "abc";
IList<string> strList = new List<string>() { "abc",  "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno" };
if (strList.Contains(name))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Got It");
}

/////////////////   OR ////////////////////////

IList<int> num = new List<int>();
num.Add(10);
num.Add(20);
num.Add(30);
num.Add(40);

Console.WriteLine(num.Count);   // to count the total numbers in the list

if(num.Contains(20)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Got It");    // if condition to find the number from list
}
```