# How to check if an integer is already in a list

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, contains

i'm currently coding my own Sudoku in Windows Forms C# and I currently have Problems how to check if an integer is already in my list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                list.Add(sodukuPlayfield.grid[i, j]);
            }
        }
```

So I add all the number in a row to a list. But after that I wanna check if there is only one number from 1 - 9.
How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you search something?

Comment: Use list.Contains(searckey)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924268/find-if-an-integer-exists-in-a-list-of-integers

Comment: How about -> if (!list.Contains(.....

Comment: Here is a similar problem with a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118212/c-sharp-list-only-contains?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure where you want to put the list checking, but this is how you check if a list contains a specific number:

`List.Contains(number you're searching for)`

Hope it helps!