# Is there anyway i can compare int with int[] in if statement? c#

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to find out if my selected int number matches with one of my numbers in my number range int[] in this code?

Skaičiuoti means Count

```
    ButųKonteineris ArTenkinaKainą(ButųKonteineris butai, int[] kainųIntervalas)
    {
        ButųKonteineris artenkinakainąbutai = new ButųKonteineris(butai.Skaičiuoti);
        for (int i = 0; i < butai.Skaičiuoti; i++)
        {
            if (butai.PaimtiButą(i).Kaina == kainųIntervalas)
            {
                butai.PridetiButą(butai.PaimtiButą(i));
            }
        }
        return artenkinakainąbutai;
    }
```

Comment: `ints.Contains(int)` ?!?

Comment: *Linq* `Any`: `if (array.Any(item => item == itemToTest)) {}`

Comment: depends how you want to compare them.

Comment: @DanielA.White - how many ways can you  do `intA == intB` ?

Comment: @RandRandom you should have made this an answer so it could be accepted.

Comment: @bommelding `new [] { intA }.Contains(intB), intA.Equals(intB), new [] { intA }.Any(i => i == intB), new [] { intA }.Where(i => i == intB).Count() > 0`  do I need to continue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find if an integer exists in a list of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924268/find-if-an-integer-exists-in-a-list-of-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the LINQ extension method `.Contains()`. So if your array of integers is called kainųIntervalas, and you want to check if it contains the integer 42, it would be

```
if (kainųIntervalas.Contains(42))
{
    // success!
}
```

Or to verify your `butai.PaimtiButą(i).Kaina`

```
if (kainųIntervalas.Contains(butai.PaimtiButą(i).Kaina))
{
    butai.PridetiButą(butai.PaimtiButą(i));
}
```

note that you need the System.Linq namespace for this:

```
using System.Linq;
```